# 2 etiquetas hr niveladas igualmente

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `<div>` donde tengo 2 `<hr>` que son 2 lineas, pero cuando quiero usar 2 o más, una se pone más abajo de otra y así.

No hay alguna forma de que estén en la misma "linea"?

```
<div class="firm">
        <div class="firmaDer"><hr align="left" width="300" color="black" size="3"></Hr></div>
        <div class="firmaIzq"><hr align="right" width="300" color="black" size="3"></Hr></div>
</div>
```

Y en la parte de estilos, nada más les tengo un margin a cada uno para que no este tan pegados al borde:

```
.firmaIzq {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.firmaDer {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

Así es como me los muestra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Por [definición](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr#:%7E:text=Definici%C3%B3n,HTML%20representaba%20una%20l%C3%ADnea%20horizontal.):

> El elemento HTML `<hr>` representa un cambio de tema entre párrafos (por ejemplo, un cambio de escena en una historia, un cambio de tema en una sección). En versiones previas de HTML representaba una línea horizontal.

Por lo que por defecto su comportamiento es dar un salto de línea, lo más fácil es encerrarlos en `div` (Como ya lo haces) y utilizar la `display: inline-block;` en los `div` y funcionará:

```css
.firmaIzq {
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.firmaDer {
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="firm">
        <div class="firmaDer"><hr align="left" width="250" color="black" size="3"/></div>
        <div class="firmaIzq"><hr align="right" width="250" color="black" size="3"/></div>
</div>
```

**Nota:** Reduje el tamaño de las líneas y el margen para que pudieran verse en el `snippet`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer flexibles el contenido de adentro y así estén los elementos uno al lado del otro, así:

```css
.firmas {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firmas">
  <hr align="left" width="230" color="black" size="3">
  <hr align="right" width="230" color="black" size="3">
</div>
```